# MySQL multiple fields foreign key referencing to single field

Tags: mysql, database

I have languages table which looks like that:

```
 -id
 -name
 -iso
```

and in multiple tables I need to reference this `iso` field as foreign key. The problem is, I can't do it even if I give completely unique FK names. What is problem?

Here is how my Languages table contructed:

```
CREATE TABLE `Languages` (
  `id` tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `iso` char(2) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `order` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Can you show exactly what you `can't do`? It's totally not a problem to have multiple foreign keys in various tables pointing to the same field.

Comment: Set FK in ID instead of iso

Comment: @raina77ow here is how my languages table look like

Comment: @raina77ow here is error that I get http://screencast.com/t/rTgkuwOeSO with Navicat. Both tables are empty, truncated. Both fields same type: varchar 3 (changed to varchar to test) And fk name is unique

Comment: @raina77ow http://screencast.com/t/tiGoWHOz

Comment: What charset/collation is used in these other tables?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you have the same column datatype in your parent and child tables. Also create an index on your parent table's iso column. In absence of details in your question about tables you currently have and SQL you used for them, let's take some examples that you can compare with your database.

Example of different datatype:

```
create table languages (
    id int,
    name varchar(100),
    iso char(3),
    primary key(id)
);
create index ix_countries_iso on languages(iso);

create table countries (
    id int,
    iso int,
    foreign key(iso) references languages(iso)
);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Example of missing index on parent table:

```
create table languages (
    id int,
    name varchar(100),
    iso char(3),
    primary key(id)
);
-- notice that we aren't creating an index on iso

create table countries (
    id int,
    iso char(3), -- notice correct datatype in child and parent table
    foreign key(iso) references languages(iso)
);
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

What if you have the same datatype in parent and child but lengths are different? I'd recommend keeping the datatype and the length same but the following statements *will* work:

```
create table languages (
    id int,
    name varchar(100),
    iso char(3),
    primary key(id)
);
create index ix_countries_iso on languages(iso);

create table countries (
    id int,
    iso char(10), -- will work, but don't do this
    foreign key(iso) references languages(iso)
);

create table countries2 (
    id int,
    iso char(1), -- will work also, but don't do this
    foreign key(iso) references languages(iso)
);
```

Let's take an example of a working solution of foreign keys that you can compare with your database structure:

```
create table languages (
    id int,
    name varchar(100),
    iso char(3),
    primary key(id)
);
create index ix_countries_iso on languages(iso);

create table countries (
    id int,
    iso char(3), -- same datatype
    foreign key fq_countries_languages(iso) references languages(iso)
);

create table boundaries (
    id int,
    iso char(3), -- same datatype
    foreign key fq_boundaries_languages(iso) references languages(iso)
);
```

I'd also recommend that your child tables that rely on foreign key should be indexed also. Check out a nice little [article on foreign keys](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/an-introduction-to-foreign-keys-and-referential-integrity-in-mysql/).

Comment: please edit your comment and remove projects name from   `CREATE TABLE ...` . It's project's name and must be confidental :)

Comment: Hi @heron, comment removed per your wish

Comment: Can you add statements of child tables that have FK troubles?